# Can you get MAC drivers for Huawei U8180?

Tags: usb, usb-drivers

I have a Huawei U8180 (sometimes called X1).

When I mount the USB I can see the SD card and there is also a tool on the device to install the Windows drivers. But can't seem to find anything for Mac.

Does anyone know if you can get Mac drivers for it so adb commands will run on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need drivers for a Mac.

What you can do so you can access adb from anywhere is create an environment variable that
points to the path of adb.

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `cd ~` this will take you to your home directory
3. Type `touch .profile` this will create a hidden file named profile
4. Type open -e .profile this will open the file you just created in TextEdit
5. In the file, type export PATH=${PATH}:/pathToTheAndroidSdkFolder/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools
6. Save file, close TextEdit, Quit Terminal, and Relaunch Terminal

now when you run `adb devices`, in a terminal, you should see something like the following:

> List of devices attached
>   5751A45CB25EF device

if you don't see anything listed for devices, make sure you have USB Debugging enabled in `Settings > Development > USB Debugging`

Comment: "make sure you have USB Debugging enabled in Settings > Development > USB Debugging" - Thanks, this did the trick. It's always the simple things that I seem to forget ...

Comment: Even with USB Debugging enabled, this didn't work for me with a related phone: a Huawei U8110 (aka T-Mobile Pulse Mini).